# Singleton with eager initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, eager-loading

I have class X that takes much time to initialize itself. I want to make that class singleton and force its creation when rails application starts.

I've made the singleton:

```
class X
  @@instance = nil

  def self.instance
    if @@instance.nil?
      @@instance = X.new
      puts 'CREATING'
    end

    return @@instance
  end

  private_class_method :new
end
```

The problem is that every time I use this class I see 'CREATING' in logs. I've tried to put creation of class in `initializers` directory but it doesn't work either.

Comment: How are you using the class? Show us. `self.instance` doesn't seem to actually return an instance, to start with...

Comment: My mistake - corrected. This is utility class I use in one method of model. I've add `require` in model and then simply `X.instance.do_something`

Comment: When I put initialization in `initializers` directory the first call to class was correct - no new object was created. But the second call caused creation of new object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that Rails in development environment doesn't cache classes and application code is reloaded every request.